# Where do you volunteer as a project manager?

Tags: career

What are the most effective/interesting places to volunteer, in the industry of project management?

Comment: yegor, in the spirit of improving the reach of your question could you clarify the following points in your question? What do you consider "effective/interesting places"?  What is your goal as a volunteer, get PM hours (aka. Experience) or something else?

Comment: Exactly, experience is the primary objective.

Comment: This is one of the old list questions from our private beta and has only 78 views as of 6/28/2012. It isn't a constructive question, since it asks for a list of items. Since there are so few answers, we *could* edit it to meet StackExchange guidelines but am closing for now to evaluate and address later.

Answer (score 3):

I'd point co-organizing a local conference or other community event. Conferences like TEDx can be pretty big (like 500 people) and there's always a need to for help. You can learn a lot about leading projects there. However remember about voluntary project specifics. See: [What can I do to prepare for managing a project which is staffed mostly with volunteers, for a non-for-profit organization?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/154/what-can-i-do-to-prepare-for-managing-a-project-which-is-staffed-mostly-with-volu)

Another idea is organizing some event, i.e. holidays, for your friends. If you approach this task thinking about it as a project you can learn pretty much. Especially that friends make pretty difficult clients - often you can't count on their discipline and you don't want to play hard balls against them (something you'd consider against clients).

Answer (score 1):

Local PMI chapter or PMI special interest group online.